# How to tune IntelliJ to build Hybris projects?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

As I know, I cannot build Hybris projects in IntelliJ, I have to use cmd + ant all.
It's because ant all from intellij and ant all from cmd are differ in something. (why?)

So how can I tune intellij to build hybris from intellij idea, not from cmd?

P.S. I think there are differences in ant all target in intellij and usual ant all, but I'm not sure.

Comment: yeah, you are right. The build on the console is different from the build in the idea. I think different files on the system are used.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the [Integration for SAP Commerce](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12639-integration-for-sap-commerce) plug-in?

Comment: Yes, I use it. But as I know (I can be wrong) it doesn't resolve the problem. Do you compile and start project from intellij?

Comment: Also, I don't see in the plugin description something about project compilation

Comment: @AntonSorokin I use Eclipse and SAP's plugin. I played with IntelliJ for a while, but went back to Eclipse. But even with Eclipse, I need to "ant all" on command-line, and to build on Eclipse separately. It's troublesome, but I got used to the workflow.

Comment: Why did you decide to use Eclipse instead of Intellij?

Comment: @AntonSorokin Majority of my colleagues use IntelliJ, but I'm more familiar with Eclipse. One reason I chose Eclipse is the concept of workspace / project, where I can see all the different projects in the workspace. IntelliJ does not work the same way. Also, Eclipse has the Problems view, which lets you see all the compilation errors in a proejct. (This can also be simulated in IntelliJ) Also, Spring Tool Suite is free. If you want Spring support in IntelliJ, you need to pay or use the EAP. Also, I prefer Eclipse's UI, where I see everything I need/want. IntelliJ is context-based.

Answer (score -2):

Install a plugin called "Integration for SAP Commerce by Janis Jansons" in IntelliJ  2019, currently, 2020 is not compatible.

start Intellij Import a project, select Hybris as the model,
[image: Import project from external sources]
Select extension you require

Once the project is loaded perfectly, on the right side you would see Ant tab,
you will find all the ant targets
[image: ant targets]